# drupal 7 include site wide contact form in a node

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want add the *Site Wide user form* a node.

I used `Drupal 7`.

The site wide form Id-s: `contact_site_form` ( I get it from `from.inc` )

With alter I *altered* the form content.

in the node code:

**php code:**

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('contact_site_form'));
```

**Error message:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: contact_site_form drupal_retrieve_form() függvényben (D:\wamp\www\online_recruitment\includes\form.inc 766 sor).
Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'contact_site_form' was given drupal_retrieve_form() függvényben (D:\wamp\www\online_recruitment\includes\form.inc 802 sor).
```

Comment: what's your problem and what have you done?

Comment: Problem: i got error when view the node.
Done: i alter the form in my module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

http://drupal.org/node/237559#comment-780448 -> D6 way but worked in D7 as wel

php: require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'contact') .'/contact.pages.inc';

it worked like a charm.